# IllegalBlockSizeException "Invalid input length" when decrypt data

Tags: android, encryption, rsa

I am developing an android app.

I want to encrypt/decrypt some sensitive data (jwt token) into SharedPreference.

So I wrote the below code.

```
fun initKeyStore() {
    val alias = "${packageName}.rsakeypairs"
    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore").apply {
        load(null)
    }

    if (keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {

    } else {
        SLog.d(LogTag.SECURE, "[cipher] No keypair for $alias, creating a new one")
        with(KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore"), {
            val spec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias,
                    PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(2048, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4))
                    .setBlockModes(BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                    .setDigests(DIGEST_SHA512, DIGEST_SHA384, DIGEST_SHA256)
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                    .build()
            initialize(spec)
            generateKeyPair()
        })
    }

    keyEntry = keyStore.getEntry(alias, null)
}

fun String.encrypt(): String? {
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, (keyEntry as KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry).certificate.publicKey)
    val bytes = this.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
    val encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(bytes)
    val base64EncryptedBytes = Base64.encode(encryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)
    return String(base64EncryptedBytes)
}

fun String.decrypt(): String {
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, (keyEntry as KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry).privateKey)
    val base64EncryptedBytes = this.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
    val encryptedBytes = Base64.decode(base64EncryptedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)
    val decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes)
    return String(decryptedBytes)
}
```

But when the app tries to decrypt the encrypted data, Exception occurred.

```
    javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:513)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055)
        ...
     Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Invalid input length
        at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1539)
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.update(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:132)
```

The length of the JWT token that I am using is very long. (More than 800)

If I try to encrypt/decrypt short text, it works fine...

How can I encrypt/decrypt the long text?

Comment: `.setBlockModes(BLOCK_MODE_CBC)` doesn't make sense for RSA. I would assume it's just ignored, but who knows. Also, the encrypt and decrypt directions need their own Cipher instances.

Answer (score 0):

In order to encrypt a long text, you either increase the key size (which is probably a bad idea, since it will take much more time to generate this key), or you split the text into chunks, encrypt those chunks one by one, and save them as a string array.

Comment: Actually, I tried to increase the key size from 2048 -> 8096.
But when it creates the keypair, an exception occurs... So... I am considering your second opinion.

Comment: This answer seems unrelated to the exception being reported.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum limit of Assymmetric Encryption  is 245 character.

it can be  fixed   with the chunks of the Long  String

```
   object SecurePreferencesHelper {
    private const val chunkSize = 240

    private fun getNumberOfChunksKey(key: String) = "${key}_numberOfChunks"

    fun setLongStringValue(key: String, value: String) {
        val chunks = value.chunked(chunkSize)

        SecurePreferences.setValue(getNumberOfChunksKey(key), chunks.size)

        chunks.forEachIndexed { index, chunk ->
            SecurePreferences.setValue("$key$index", chunk)
        }
    }

    fun getLongStringValue(key: String): String? {
        val numberOfChunks = SecurePreferences.getIntValue(getNumberOfChunksKey(key), 0)

        if (numberOfChunks == 0) {
            return null
        }

        return (0 until numberOfChunks)
                .map { index ->
                    val string = SecurePreferences.getStringValue("$key$index", null) ?: run {
                        return null
                    }

                    string
                }.reduce { accumulator, chunk -> accumulator + chunk }
    }

    fun removeLongStringValue(key: String) {
        val numberOfChunks = SecurePreferences.getIntValue(getNumberOfChunksKey(key), 0)

        (0 until numberOfChunks).map { SecurePreferences.removeValue("$key$it") }
        SecurePreferences.removeValue(getNumberOfChunksKey(key))
    }

    fun containsLongStringValue(key: String): Boolean {
        return SecurePreferences.contains(getNumberOfChunksKey(key))
    }
}
```

For reference pls refer link

[click here](https://github.com/adorsys/secure-storage-android/issues/28)